# Difference between "try" and "if"

Tags: python, if-statement

Is there any functional difference in Python between a "try" statement and an "if" statement?

Comment: There is a *huge* difference between them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you're asking about the paradigm "Easier to ask for forgiveness than for permission" which is sometimes quoted as a Python guideline.

In this context `try / except` corresponds to trying and asking for forgiveness, while `if` corresponds to asking for permission then trying.

Have a look: http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp

Comment: Yws I was, sorry I didn't make that more explicit in my initial question.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the [documention](http://docs.python.org/index.html), [try](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html) is for exception, [if](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html) is for conditional branches.

Answer (score 2):

One branches based on error state, the other branches based on truth value comparison. Sure, you could use `try`-`except` blocks in place of `if`-`else` blocks if you really wanted to by having an error raised when a condition is `False` as the first portion of the `try` block, but that would be silly.

Comment: How would you check if condition is `False` to raise the error? ;)

Comment: `try: assert statement; "true" code; except AssertionError: "false" code;`

Answer (score 2):

if statement is for control the flow of the code like this

```
a=1

if a ==0 :
    print "zero"
if a==1 :
    print "one"
```

but, try statement is for control some errors could be. Like you want to open a file and this file dont exist, then you write.

```
try:
    open ('file.txt','r')
except:
    print "this file dont exists"
```

With this code the program dont crasses